# pointer to incomplete class type "struct pt_regs" is not allowed

Tags: c, linux

When compiling the kernel using `make -j4`, I got the following error:

```
./arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess_64.h:56:1: error: conflicting types for ‘raw_copy_to_user’; have ‘long unsigned int(void *, const void *, long unsigned int)’
   56 | raw_copy_to_user(void __user *dst, const void *src, unsigned long size)
```

so I thought it might be because of getting an error:

```
pointer to incomplete class type "struct pt_regs" is not allowedC/C++(393) on SYSCALL_DEFINE2.
```

```
// strcpy.c: code for the new system call
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/slab.h> // kmalloc()
#include <asm-generic/uaccess.h> // copy_from_user()
#include <linux/syscalls.h> // SYSCALL_DEFINE2

typedef unsigned int __bitwise gfp_t;

SYSCALL_DEFINE2(strcpy, char*, dest, char*, src) {
int i = 0, size;
char *tmp1, *tmp2;
size = 1 + strlen(src) * sizeof(char);
tmp1 = (char *) kmalloc(size, GFP_KERNEL);
tmp2 = (char *) kmalloc(size, GFP_KERNEL);
if (copy_from_user(tmp1, src, size) == 0) {
tmp2[0] = tmp1[0];
while(tmp1[i++] != '\0') tmp2[i] = tmp1[i];
} else {
printk(KERN_ALERT "error memory access\n");
return 0;
}
if (copy_to_user(dest, tmp2, size) != 0) {
printk(KERN_ALERT "error memory access\n");
return 0;
}
kfree(tmp1); kfree(tmp2);
printk(KERN_ALERT "done system call strcpy...\n");
return 1;
}
```

configuration:

```
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
               "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/**",

            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cpptools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

and here is the configuration file: c_cpp_properties.json
the struct error is on the word: SYSCALL_DEFINE2

Comment: Please, don't post image of code, instead edit your post and copy/paste it.

Comment: the struct is SYSCALL_DEFINE2 itself

Comment: "The kernel" as in the *Linux* kernel?  What does Visual Studio Code have to do with that?  Use the kernel's standard configuration and build process, and keep VSC out of it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger just using VSCODE as an editor

Comment: Then VSCode configuration has nothing to do with any compilation errors you receive.

Comment: Please present an excerpt of the `make` output showing the command that produced the error(s) and the full list of diagnostics from that command.  Also, please confirm that `make -j4` was the full command used to launch the compilation, or else present the full command that actually was used.

Comment: Note that `strlen(src);` should be `strlen_user(src);` and parentheses are requireed to distribute the `* sizeof(char)`. I.e. `size = 1 + strlen(src) * sizeof(char);` should be `size = (1 + strlen_user(src)) * sizeof(char);` or preferably, skip the `* sizeof(char)` and use `size = 1 + strlen_user(src);`

Comment: Do verify that the name of your source file is really `strcpy.c`.  That is, **not** `strcpy.cpp`, `strcpy.C`, `strcpy.c.cpp`, or similar.

Comment: Why do you have a typedef for `gfp_t`? It should be defined by the existing `#include` directives.

Comment: You should not use `#include <asm-generic/uaccess.h>`. You should use `#include <asm/uaccess.h>` or preferably `#include <linux/uaccess.h>`. That is very likely to be the cause of the error message.

Comment: There are memory leaks in the function. When it returns 0 it does not free the memory it has allocated. Also, you need to check that the calls to `kmalloc` do not return `NULL`.

Comment: @lan <asm/uaccess.h> is not being recognized. and I got this error `cannot open source file "asm/facility-defs.h" (dependency of "asm/uaccess.h")C/C++(1696)`

Answer (score 1):

It says "pointer to incomplete **class** type" which means that you are compiling C code with a C++ compiler. The solution is either to reinstall your C compiler (`sudo apt reinstall gcc`), or to edit the Makefile if you made any changes to it.

Comment: I am already using gcc compiler. As for the Makefile, I created a folder "CMPS" in the linux source folder: /usr/src/linux-5.19.9/CMPS/ in which I added the strcpy1.c. so I edited the MakeFile in the src folder /usr/src/linux-5.19.9 as such: `ifeq ($(KBUILD_EXTMOD),)
core-y   += kernel/ certs/ mm/ fs/ ipc/ security/ crypto/ block/ CMPS240
core-$(CONFIG_BLOCK) += block/ CMPS240/`

Comment: @Mals Sorry, I wrote the wrong command. The logic behind reinstalling GCC is that the shortcut to it may have been overridden by another compiler. I edited the answer to the right command ("apt reinstall").

Comment: still getting thethe conflicting type error.  here is my configuration file: `{ 
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
               "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/**",

            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cpptools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
`

Comment: kindly find above the configuration file(in the post above)

Comment: @Mals Now that I think about it, C++ shouldn't cause that error either, so I did some reasearch and apparently the error "incomplete class" or "incomplete type" means that you declared a type like this: ```struct bla;``` and didn't actually define it. The struct pt_regs is defined in this file: linux/asm/ptrace.h, so maybe try including it in your code and it will work?

Comment: @SamuelAmmoniusSTUDENT Linux won't compile as C++ anyways. Linux uses some C++ keywords like `class` as variable names, so it's not valid C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the conflicting types is the use of `#include <asm-generic/uaccess.h>`. Header files in `asm-generic/` should never be included directly by normal Linux kernel code. Use `asm/` instead.  For `uaccess.h` it is preferable to use `#include <linux/uaccess.h>` instead of `#include <asm/uaccess.h>`, at least since kernel version 2.6.18.

There are other problems with the code:

1. The line `typedef unsigned int __bitwise gfp_t;` is not required; The `gfp_t` type will be defined in the included header files.
2. `strlen` should not be called pointers to user memory such as the `src` parameter; call `strlen_user` instead.
3. In the calculation `1 + strlen(src) * sizeof(char)`, the multiplication has not been distributed properly. It could be changed to `(1 + strlen(src)) * sizeof(char)` to make logical sense, but since `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition, it can be changed to `1 + strlen(src)` (except that it needs to use `strlen_user` in this case, as described above).
4. The function does not check the result on the calls to `kmalloc`. All memory allocations in kernel code should be checked for success.
5. The function has a memory leak when it returns 0 without freeing the memory blocks pointed to by `tmp1` and `tmp2`.
6. The `src` parameter type should be `const char*`.
7. The `dest` and `src` parameter types should be tagged as pointers to user memory; they should be `char __user*` and `const char __user*`, respectively.

Comment: @lan with the same code, this time it compiled but not successfully. i didn't face any of the errors now it is the following the error: `make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'init/built-in.o', needed by 'vmlinux.o'.  Stop.`